# Assuming that the US reduces its citizenship renunciation fee, which country has the highest citizenship renunciation fee?

Tags: citizenship

I read on [sestiniandco.com](https://www.sestiniandco.com/us-citizenship-renunciation-fees/):

> This month (7 January 2023), the US government has announced plans to reduce its fee for the citizenship renunciation scheme from US$2,350 to just US$450.

Assuming that the US reduces its citizenship renunciation fee, which country has the highest citizenship renunciation fee?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a polling question which has no meaning or value.

Comment: Apart from a general knowledge quiz question, what is the **actual problem** that getting an answer to this would solve?

Comment: Are you already planning to renounce your US citizenship?  Just last year you were asking about naturalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a list of citizenship renunciation costs on https://www.movehub.com/blog/dual-citizenship-around-the-world-map/:

| Country | Price (USD) |
| --- | --- |
| Ireland | 0 - Free |
| Japan | 0 - Free |
| South Africa | 0 - Free |
| Sweden | 0 - Free |
| Malaysia | 4.00 |
| South Korea | 20.00 |
| Singapore | 27.00 |
| Germany | 28.16 |
| Taiwan | 30.00 |
| Russia | 31.43 |
| Cyprus | 33.79 |
| China | 39.33 |
| Dominica | 44.44 |
| Nigeria | 50.00 |
| Tanzania | 60.00 |
| Hong Kong | 74.00 |
| Canada | 76.64 |
| Colombia | 80.00 |
| Peru | 87.00 |
| Israel | 92.00 |
| Vietnam | 118.00 |
| Pakistan | 150.00 |
| Denmark | 166.02 |
| India | 175.00 |
| Australia | 203.63 |
| Kenya | 216.00 |
| Italy | 225.26 |
| New Zealand | 254.73 |
| UK | 339.41 |
| Lebanon | 350.00 |
| Ghana | 400.00 |
| Poland | 404.95 |
| Sierra Leone | 663.00 |
| Egypt | 800.00 |
| Jamaica | 1010.00 |
| USA | 2350.00 |

Unfortunately, most countries are missing from this list.

Comment: Are those figures all expressed in USD?

Comment: @phoog I assume so, since it’s USD for the USA price and I don’t think other rows would use a different currency

Comment: For [Germany the fee is €51](https://www.bayernportal.de/dokumente/leistung/7041386171125?plz=85748&behoerde=62442374446&gemeinde=969968710674) and for [Poland €360](https://www.gov.pl/web/deutschland/verzicht-auf-polnischen-staatsangehrigkeit), so this source doesn't look reliable.

Comment: @MarkJohnson thanks, it's not too far away (within 30 EUR), maybe prices have shifted slightly.

Comment: No, it has been €51 since at least 2007-08-28. [Fassung § 38 StAG a.F. bis 28.08.2007 (geändert durch Artikel 5 G. v. 19.08.2007 BGBl. I S. 1970)](https://www.buzer.de/gesetz/4560/al8350-0.htm)

Comment: @MarkJohnson thanks, I welcome other answers :)

Comment: @MarkJohnson it's conceivable (if not likely) that the EUR/USD exchange rate was 1.125 when the Polish figure was added to the table.  The German figure does indeed seem to bespeak unreliability, though if I'm reading it correctly the law says that the fee is set by the ministry and may not be higher than €51; it's possible that it was less than that maximum for some time.  In fact at https://www.bva.bund.de/DE/Services/Buerger/Ausweis-Dokumente-Recht/Staatsangehoerigkeit/Verzicht/01_Informationen_Verzicht/01_03_V_Gebuehren/01_03_V_Gebuehren_node.html it appears that the fee is €0.

Comment: @phoog Good grief, do some research before making such derogatory comments. **Fact 1**: the source is from 2023. **Fact 2**: the fee in Germany has been (for many,many,many years) €51 for the  Dismissal certificate (Entlassungsurkunde). **Fact 3**: the second sentance of your source (which you neglected to meantion) states: *Please keep in mind that you may incur costs for obtaining documents, translations and **certifications***. (€360 / 1.125 = $320 and not anywhere near $400)